# preg_replace postive negative and 0

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am using `preg_replace` here:

```
$listing = preg_replace('/[^-?\d|.]/', '', $data);
```

But print only negative and positive numbers without 0.
I want to print negative, positive, and zero.

I have also tried this, but without success:

```
$listing = preg_replace('/[^-?\0-9|.]/', '', $data);
```

Comment: Please show us sample input along with the output you want.

Comment: in number input field i put positive negative or 0, and also i want to show

Comment: Fixed English and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *capture* all numbers, then use `preg_match_all`, with the pattern `(?<!\S)-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`:

```
$data = "Hello -1.2345 world 0 and 3.1459 goodbye too";
preg_match_all("/(?<!\S)-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/", $data, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => -1.2345
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 3.1459
)
```

On the other hand, if you want to *remove* all positive and negative numbers (and zero), then try using the same pattern with `preg_replace`:

```
$data = "Hello -1.2345 world 0 and 3.1459 goodbye too";
$listing = preg_replace("/(?<!\S)-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/", "", $data);
echo $listing;
```

This prints:

```
Hello  world  and  goodbye too
```

Comment: i want to show all positive negative and 0 from input form

Comment: I updated with an option for capturing all numbers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Anything within square brackets is a character class. That means it defines a single character, and is not subject to the usual regular expression syntax. You have `[^-?\d|.]` which defines a character class excluding the characters `-`, `?`, any number, a pipe, or a period.

I suspect what you're looking for is something like this:

```
$listing = preg_replace('/[^0-9.-]/', '', $data);
```